# undefined while testing a function

Tags: javascript

so I've been working on functions making star patterns and somehow I keep getting "undefined" when i ´innerHTML´ it. Can anyone help me to see what I'm doing wrong here?

```
pOutput.innerHTML = square(3);
poutput.innerHTML = rectangle(2,3);

function square(x) {
var z;
for (var i = 1; i<=x; i++) {
    for ( var j = 1; j<=x; j++) {
        z += "*";
    }
    z += "<br>";
}  
return z
}

function rectangle(x, y) {
var z;
for (var i = 1; i<=x; i++) {
    for ( var j = 1; j<=y; j++) {
        z += "*";
    }
    z += "<br>";
}  
return z  
}
```

Comment: `var z;` <--- undefined....

Comment: Sidenote, For better practices you should add semicolons `;` to your returns. Also don't name variables that only differ with case (poutput vs pOutput). poutput isn't a very descriptive name anyway. Your first function can also be shortened down to 1 line: `return rectangle(x, x);` :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do `var z = ""` otherwise the value is **undefined**, see this:

```js
var z;

console.log(z)
```

Full example:

```js
console.log(square(3));
console.log(rectangle(2,3));

function square(x) {
var z = "";
for (var i = 1; i<=x; i++) {
    for ( var j = 1; j<=x; j++) {
        z += "*";
    }
    z += "<br>";
}  
return z
}

function rectangle(x, y) {
var z = "";
for (var i = 1; i<=x; i++) {
    for ( var j = 1; j<=y; j++) {
        z += "*";
    }
    z += "<br>";
}  
return z  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following snippet where I have fixed your code. You need to initialize z with empty string.

```
var z = "";
```

If it is undefined following thing went wrong

```
z += "*" -> z is undefined so z = "undefined" + "*"
```

```js
document.getElementById("square").innerHTML = square(3);
document.getElementById("rectangle").innerHTML = rectangle(2, 3);

function square(x) {
  var z = "";
  for (var i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= x; j++) {
      z += "*";
    }
    z += "<br/>";
  }
  return z
}

function rectangle(x, y) {
  var z = "";
  for (var i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= y; j++) {
      z += "*";
    }
    z += "<br/>";
  }
  return z
}
```

```html
Square
<div id="square"></div>

<br/><br/> Rectangle
<div id="rectangle"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `z` with "" default value of `z` is `undefined` at var z;

```
var pOutput = document.getElementById('pOutput')
var poutput = document.getElementById('poutput')
pOutput.innerHTML = square(3);
poutput.innerHTML = rectangle(2,3);

function square(x) {
var z = "";
for (var i = 1; i<=x; i++) {
    for ( var j = 1; j<=x; j++) {
        z += "*";
    }
    z += "<br>";
}  
return z
}

function rectangle(x, y) {
var z = "";
for (var i = 1; i<=x; i++) {
    for ( var j = 1; j<=y; j++) {
        z += "*";
    }
    z += "<br>";
}  
return z  
}
```